# Why isn't my gsub() function (to replace + and -) in my Shiny app working?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use gsub() to replace "+" in column names with "pos" and "-" with "neg". I wrote the following code:

```
  clean_df <- reactive({
    mydf <- clean_names(mydf())
    names(mydf) <- gsub('\\+', 'pos', names(mydf()))
    names(mydf) <- gsub('\\-', 'neg', names(mydf()))
    return(mydf())
  })
```

It doesn't seem to do anything though. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `mydf()` which is a function call, and not the data frame whose names you have replaced.  Try this version:

```r
clean_df <- reactive({
    mydf <- clean_names(mydf)
    names(mydf) <- gsub('\\+', 'pos', names(mydf))
    names(mydf) <- gsub('\\-', 'neg', names(mydf))
    return(mydf)
})
```